# Tmux and Vi in PuTTY = No arrow keys in Vi

Tags: tmux, vi

I'm using PuTTY as my terminal with tmux. At first I couldn't resize panes so based on [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=AANLkTikZmydrdGvcZxTVX3qb_LBv7ia3PSdz1ygA_9y1@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=tmux-users) I added the below to my .tmux.conf"

```
set -g terminal-overrides "*:kUP5=\eOA,*:kDN5=\eOB,*:kLFT5=\eOD,*:kRIT5=\eOC"
```

A pointer to anyone trying the above config change, you have to kill all tmux sessions for changes to .tmux.conf to be acknowledged, simply detaching and reattaching won't work.

But after making this change I can no longer use the arrow keys to move the cursor in vi. How can I get arrows working for pane resizing and cursor movements in vi?